# getting GTX1050 drivers working on Ubuntu for Lenovo Yoga 720

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

Everything on my Yoga 720 is working fine except the graphics card. On my first install, I could tell that Ubuntu was not using my graphics card by going `glxinfo|egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer*"`. When I boot in grub I *must* select `nomodeset` or else it hangs on a purple screen. I then tried to update the graphics card drivers using this example and replacing with relevant drivers http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in-linux . Then when I booted in grub, no matter what it froze on starting the nvidia persistence daemon. I then had to disable switchable graphics in my BIOS to boot back into Ubuntu. Has anyone had any luck getting graphics card drivers working for their lenovo 720? As a side (this may be related to the install in some capacity), Ubuntu also freezes on reboot/shutdown.